# Scala Composing Functional Interfaces

Tags: scala

I have the following functional interfaces:

```
scala> object FromString extends (String => Int) {
     | def apply(a: String) = a.length
     | }
defined object FromString

scala> object FromInt extends (Int => Int) {
     | def apply(a: Int) = a * a
     | }
defined object FromInt
```

How do I use functional composition to effectively chain my functional interfaces above?

Comment: Do you just want a function composition operator? You can use `andThen`: `val f: String => Int = FromString andThen FromInt`

Comment: Can't I just do FromString("a") andThen FromInt(_)... something like that? It fails when I tried it

Comment: It must be interface and not functions ? It will works with functions instead of objects.

Comment: Hmm... I call this functional interface and there mush be a possibility to compose them!

Comment: ```scala> val f = (((s : String) => s.length) andThen ((x : Int)  => x * x))
f: String => Int = scala.Function1$$Lambda$1109/368603167@4ed9f7b1

scala> f("hello world")
res9: Int = 121```. Something like that is not acceptable for you needs ?

Comment: `FromString("a")` has type `Int` which doesn't have an `andThen` method. Do you have an example of what you're trying to do? What type do you expect the result of the composition to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call andThen or compose directly on that singleton objects, since they extend Function1 trait:

```
(FromString andThen FromInt)("abc") // 9
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me!